# How can I improve this slow query in my wordpress site?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mariadb, wordpress

```
SELECT object_id, term_taxonomy_id
FROM wp_term_relationships
INNER JOIN wp_posts
ON object_id = ID
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (525627,516360,525519,535782,517555,525186,517572,549564,1,517754,541497,541472,525476,549563,517633,524859,702393,541604,543483,524646,525001,550518,541516,525244,549565,517376,535783,524642,25,533395,533537,525475,2,705306,524684,525065,939122,541603,525523,533491,541590,702713,550724,525243,533634,525122,541498,549586,546982,21,524643,541478,525435,535784,541471,516611,535781,541638,516142,533416,546984,524999,533453,524682,704994,516579,516189,524644,517378,525185,541508,517634,705305,524858,517632,541637,517699,525064,517573,772367,516609,517375,525474,507436,524918,517635,541929,22,54,53,705119,524685,524683,516577,536343,191228,524915,524917,516298,541573,546983,515904,541601,56,517377,524645,517707,515905,516297,515903,517708,533635,516296,516578,517750,517554,516016,525123,533538,541625,525187,705307,55,191226,19,24,516299,541466,524916,772366,555654,516612,541503,191227,550302,991853,920642,191229,535829,525582,525524,524919,524720,525841,517636,541504,525184,525520,541562,525433,541563,516610)
AND post_type IN ('post')
AND post_status = 'publish' +
_pad_term_counts()
```

Theme   259514  2.0440

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE 1=1
AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (391534)
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2,516296,517375,517376,517377,517378,517554,517555,517572,517573,517632,517633,517634,517635,517636,517699,517707,517708,517750,517754,524858,524859,524915,524916,524917,524918,524919,524999,525001,525064,525065,525185,525186,525187,525519,525520,525523,525524,525582,525841,533395,533416,533453,535782,535783,535784,535829,536343,549563,549564,549565,549586,550302,550518,550724,555654,702393,702713,704994,705119,705305,705306,705307,772366,772367,920642,939122,991853) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 6
```

How can I improve this query ? I have many posts and they are taking like 2secs each.

Thanks

I also found this extra info that I think would help...

> Why do you think modifying WordPress core table is a good idea? –
>   Krzysiek Dróżdż♦ Jun 12 '15 at 4:21 I really don't think it's a good
>   idea but a necessary one if running wordpress with the amount of posts
>   and combined with the limitations of mysql not having a descending
>   index function. Those file sorts caused by the order by operations are
>   a deal breaker for us in regards to site performance. – Ranknoodle Jun
>   15 '15 at 2:34 But these operations are slow since you're doing it
>   wrong. In some projects we had similar issue, but came to very
>   different solution, that didn't modify core tables. We've created our
>   own table and used it as indexing/search table. So every slow query
>   was searching only based on this one table (no joins needed). (And we
>   had much more data, AFAIR) – Krzysiek Dróżdż♦ Jun 15 '15 at 5:06 Hi
>   KRZYSIEK can you explain a little more on indexing search tables that
>   you created? For example the slow query outline in the original
>   question, I would create a table to store the post
>   ID,reverse_post_id,post_type etc and only query against that? –
>   Ranknoodle Jun 15 '15 at 16:31 Send me an e-mail, I'll try to
>   elaborate on that method. – Krzysiek Dróżdż♦ Jun 15 '15 at 16:34

But no idea on the method he used.

Comment: Can you add explain plan to it ?

Comment: Please post EXPLAIN (your query);   for each of the queries so we can see what the optimizer will try to do with your request.  In your second query you have a line - AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (391534) - would this force looking at every row other than this single wp_posts.ID ?  How many rows of output would this generate?

Comment: Do you have a link to Krzysiek Dróżdż's comments?

Comment: Krzysiek Dróżdż's link comments: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189736/optimize-wordpress-query-that-take-5-seconds-to-execute

Answer (score 0):

`'publish'` is a string

`+` is an _arithmetic operator

So  `'publish' + _pad_term_counts()`  is probably not anything useful.

How long does each `SELECT` take?

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT` and how big the tables are.

Descending index -- Not a problem; MySQL simply scans through the data in reverse order.

However, no index is useful for the one `ORDER BY` you mentioned -- This is because the `GROUP BY` is needed first.  Can that be removed?

Comment: thanks for help @Rick James but this just looks like a lot more research is needed